# Estimate variables which sum to zero?

Tags: regression, estimation, constraint

Assume we have $y_i$ such that $\sum y_i=0$.
Assume we have estimation machinery (some machine learning) which can estimate each $y_i$.
So we can forget constraint and eastimate each of them, or we can estimate (n-1) of them and assign one of them as minus sum of estimates, or plenty other ways.

So the question is:

What is the best way to choose for estimation of $y_i$ taking into account constraint $\sum_i y_i = 0$  ?

I guess it should be standard question, but cannot google it.

Comment: Is it the only constraint? The variables are unbounded?

Comment: @Tim for the moment let us consider it is the only constraint. Variables , well, who knows, but probably  from some Poisson distribution or may be even normal one.
Any idea is welcome. For any distribution.

Comment: If they were bounded, you could use something like Dirichlet or multimodal and rescale.

Comment: Would this not be a standard optimization with a constraint, basically a Lagrange multiplier problem?

Comment: @tim bounded you mean we know they are from some fixed intervals [a_i b_i] ?

Comment: could explain what you mean by "estimating $y_i$" and how this problem arises in a practical situation?